# Prevent myself from sending more than one message every 2 seconds in skype

Tags: windows-8.1, skype

`I have this bad habit

Of talking in skype

Like this

And it annoys people.`

I figured that if I did something like this:

[image]

It will basically force me to stop typing like that. Is there a way to add a floodcheck to myself?

I'm using skype 6.14 desktop.

Comment: What OS? What Skype version?

Comment: We here at superuser

Comment: are committed to

Comment: Helping you out!

Comment: I think that you will need to be using a web-based skype session to accomplish this.  There are some great Javascripts that do this even right here on stackoverflow.  Just try to post a comment more than once every 15 seconds or edit a comment more than once every 5 seconds....

Comment: well....  isn't the issue you're splitting text of the same sentence onto several  lines? Waiting 2 second won't prevent this.  And if you have to wait 2 seconds, then you will still be writing over multiple lines but takinit now is taking longer meaning, its even more annoying?!

Comment: @DaveRook If I can't type more than once every two seconds I won't be able to type like I said in the body - It only takes about 1/4th a second for me to type out the small lines.